# Which API creates bar chart aggregation on Timeline?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

The Facebook Game "SongPop" has an aggregate of "Most Victories" appear on a person's timeline. The presentation is in the form of a bar chart.

[image: SongPop Most Victories Aggregation on Timeline]

I'm guessing that this has been created by submitting an object to the Open Graph each time a user experiences a "Victory", and then Facebook will aggregate these for the timeline.

I'd like to know: **How can I do the same? Which object, actions or API can I use?**

(I'm using both the Javascript and PHP SDKs and am indifferent as to which one is used to make the submission - an answer which provides a solution in terms of a POST to an Open Graph URL would do nicely).

Comment: Same here. Maybe someone from FB can answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is Profile data (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/#external_profile) used with Win action type in list layout form style. Sort by favorite and caption line is something like  {count} victories

Hope that helps. Thanks